# egyg33k Bundle , generating csv from an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to generate a csv file with egyg33k bundle which I'm using in my symfony project.

I have a twig which contains two date picker inputs and a button. When I click on the button I get the values of the two date pickers and pass them to the php action to use them on a query builder (all of this works), but the file doesn't start downloading. Instead I get the content at the browser console (see photo)
moreover the action was working before using ajax.

[image: Photo 1]

ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#get_extract").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/back-office/extraction",
        data: {
            begin_date: $("#begin_date").val(),
            end_date: $("#end_date").val()
        }
    })
});
});
```

PHP:

```
public function getExtractRecordsAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->query->get('showJson') == 1) {
        $beginDate = $request->get('begin_date');
        $endDate   = $request->get('end_date');

        $recordsRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Record::class);
        $query             = $recordsRepository->createQueryBuilder('r')
             ->where('r.createdAt BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate')
            ->setParameter('beginDate', $beginDate)
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
            ->getQuery();

        $records = $query->getResult();
        $writer = $this->container->get('egyg33k.csv.writer');
        $csv    = $writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());
        $csv->insertOne([
            'ID',
            'FIRST_NAME',
            'LAST_NAME',
            'CIVILITY',
            'PHONE_NUMBER',
            'EMAIL',
            'ZIP_CODE',
            'OPTIN',

        ]);
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $csv->insertOne([
                $record->getId(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getFirstName(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getLastName(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getCivility(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getPhoneNumber(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getEmail(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getZipCode(),
                $record->getPersonalDetails()->getOptin(),

               
            ]);
        }
        $csv->output('EXAMPLE.csv');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, please extend your ajax call, it just download the data you need to force the download of the file. Actually the ajax call transfer the data from remote to local browser so you just need a way to let the browser putting everything inside a file and starting the local download (from browser to Download folder)

`$("#get_extract").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/back-office/extraction",
        data: {
            begin_date: $("#begin_date").val(),
            end_date: $("#end_date").val()
        },
        success: function(csv_content) {
          let filename = 'data.csv';
          let csvFile = new Blob([csv_content], {type: "text/csv"});
          let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
          downloadLink.download = filename;
          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
        }
    })`

Comment: Thank you so much ! you made my day ! it worked ! keep up ! :D

Comment: @mblaettermann Users need at least 15 reputation points to be able to upvote